# How can I remove the menu bar in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want to create a clean user interface for my students to use QGIS. I tried to remove the menu bar using the customization in setting but I am not able to remove everything, e.g. Database, plugin, etc. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: How much are you removing? How will they load layers without the menu bar's 'File' dropdown?

Comment: Oops, I will keep enough of the toolbar so that all the basic operations are still possible. Just could not figure out how to remove the menu bar on top.

Comment: Users probably expect to see a menu bar at the top - the toolbar icons can be a bit hard to figure out what they do at first. I'd say keep the menu bar and start with no buttonbars. If you really do turn off the menu bar you might accidentally turn off the ability to turn it back on again...

Comment: I am mindful of that and the team prefer to keep the customization option out of the students' reach.

Answer (score 4):

If you go the the Settings > Customisation menu options, it gives you a dialog that allows you to turn off whole toolbars and also remove menus and docks. You can also remove individual buttons or menu items too rather than the whole toolbar or menu.

You can also save these settings from this panel to an ini file, and then open an ini file on another machine.

This blog post talks about the feature:

http://linfiniti.com/2011/07/customizing-the-qgis-ui/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have tried the customization option, despite turning off the menus, I still cannot turn off Vector, Database and Web. There is no such option in the check boxes. Or should I look elsewhere? Please see the image below. [link]https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--aogZY8SXPw/UGA93tE3FcI/AAAAAAAAAmw/cwMGgtwidaw/s512/example.jpg

Comment: I believe this has been fixed and will be in a future release of QGIS.

Comment: If you use the the "Settings > Customisation" menu options, you need to restart qgis.

Answer (score 2):

Vector, Database and Web menu entries should vanish if you deactivate all connected plugins. For vector that would be (at least) ftools plugin.

Comment: Is there a way for me to load the plugin (e.g. ftools) but hide the vector menu? I really want to remove all the items in the menu bar, leaving only a few icons in the tool bar.

Comment: Only if you want to mess with the plugin source code.